# How can I change this linearlayout background color?

Tags: android, colors, background, icons

I want to set `transparent` background color on `LinearLayout`.

I've just set image resource and icon border color. I haven't set gray background color but linearlayout's background looks gray. I couldn't change this.

Is it possible that my mistake using `GradientDrawable`, causing it to happen?

I tried `setBackgroundColor(getColor(R.color.transparent));` or xml `android:background="@color/transparent"` but not working.

How can I do that?

> **My xml layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        android:gravity="center" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/imageDescription"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</LinearLayout>
```

> **My code:**

```
 icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.up);

 //set icon border color
 GradientDrawable drawable = (GradientDrawable) getBackground();
 drawable.setStroke(4, R.color.orange);
```

[image]

Comment: try this color code android.R.color.transparent

Comment: can u define a transparent color in `Color.xml` ?

Comment: not working @PawanSinghChauhan :( yeap it is defined MohammadAli

Comment: please try this one **`android:background="@android:color/white"`** in your xml file

Comment: why did you get downvote?

Answer (score 1):

Just set below property to your LinearLayout in XML file

```
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```

Comment: Yes this should work. @android:color/transparent itself has opacity set and it is transparent. Probably its your imageView background that may cause issue.

Comment: please delete your answer